# workbook calculation to automatic in both vba and python

Tags: python, excel, vba

how to make excel workbook calculation to automatic in both vba and python script?

I tried this Application.Calculation = xlCalculateAutomatic but it is not working.

It throws me below error.

global name 'xlCalculateAutomatic' is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

It is `xlCalculationAutomatic` or you could use the number -4105 in Python.

Comment: Even the above one is not working. I get the same error global name 'xlCalculateAutomatic' is not defined.